# awk CSV Split with headers Windows

Tags: csv, awk

Ok I have a csv file I need to split based on a column value which is fine, but I cannot get the headers to print in each file.

Currently I use:

```
awk "FS =\",\" {output=$3\".csv\"; print $0 > output}" test.csv
```

Which splits the files file based on column 3, but I don't know how to add the header to each file.

I've searched high & low but can't find a solution that will work in a one liner...

### UPDATE

OK to date we have a working one liner:

```
awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}" test.csv
```

Or in test.awk:

```
BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1 {hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files) {files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3".csv"}
```

Command to run used:

```
awk -f test.awk test.csv
```

I really appreciate the help here, I've been trying for hours and have a few things left to work out.

1) Blank line inserted after header
2) Sort the data on specified fields

Further down the line I want to additionally do a row count & cut a reference number from another file is this possible with AWK or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Thanks again.

Comment: I think this should be posted to serverfault or superuser instead, it's off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: if you're on Windows, save the awk script in a file and run it as `awk -f file ...` to save yourself the MS quoting nightmare. Or install cygwin and run awk under that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED#2**

Blank line after header line

**UPDATED**

Try this:

On Unix/cygwin (I tested on cygwin):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr"\n">$3".csv"}{print>$3".csv"}' test.csv
```

Or adding Kent's ideas:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{hdr=$0;next}{out=$3".csv"}!($3 in files){files[$3];print hdr"\n">out}{print>out}' test.csv
```

On windows cmd (not tested):

```
awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr\"\n\">$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}" test.csv
```

This stores the header line in `test.csv` to `hdr`. For the next lines it checks if the file name value is already exists. If not then stores its name in the `files` hash and prints the header line. And anyway it prints the whole line to the file.

Example file:

```
$ cat test.csv 
A,B,C,D
1,2,a,3
4,5,b,4
```

Output

```
$ cat a.csv 
A,B,C,D

1,2,a,3

$ cat b.csv 

A,B,C,D
4,5,b,4
```

**ADDED**

If You would like to put the `awk` script into a file You could try (I cannot test is, sorry).

test.awk

```
BEGIN{FS=","} 
NR==1 {hdr=$0;next}
!($3 in files) {files[$3]=1;print hdr"\n">$3".csv"}
{print>"$3.csv"}
```

Then You may call it as

```
awk -f test.awk test.csv
```

Comment: awk -F, 'NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3".csv"}' test.csv

Comment: @TrueY OP is running it in windows. He got same error for all 4 answers! So either we all are wrong or he needs  to modify the script to run on windows! :)

Comment: @Paul: I added a windows version. Try it, pls!

Comment: Hey this looks good, still testing but thanks to everybody. I'll post better feedback shortly. Sorry about the windows thing, I thought if I saved as an afk it would be ok....

Comment: I had to modify slightly to get the file extensions, but this works perfect, Thanks so much.

Comment: @Paul: The pleasure is mine! :) Could You show Your modification? Then I could add to my answer.

Comment: @Jaypal: Thanks! I added the windows version as well.

Comment: Sure current working version is:

awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}" test.csv

Only issue is when I save it as a .awk file I get the following:

C:\tmp>awk -f test.awk
awk: test.awk:1: awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr
>$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}" test.csv
awk: test.awk:1:
                                    ^ syntax error
errcount: 1

Comment: @Paul: My version works in the command line. IMHO You do not need to escape `"` characters in the script file! So do not use `\"` before and after the extensions, just `"`.

Comment: Yeah Tried that still get an error: awk: test.awk:1: awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr
>$3".csv"}{print>$3".csv"}" test.csv
awk: test.awk:1:
                                ^ syntax error
errcount: 2

I've tried single quotes as well..... Anybody Know what's up here?

Comment: @Paul: What is in your test.awk? I assume You added `"` around the line, which are not needed. If You do not want to define `-F,` in the command line You can add to `test.awk` `BEGIN{FS=","}` to the beginning.

Comment: Morning Paul, thanks for all your help yesterday. I've updated the questions now with full description on the final issue which is converting to a .awk, really can't find that much out there. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul: I addec the corrected script at the end of my anwser. Read [man awk(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/), You could find a lot if useful tips.

Comment: @TrueY Thanks so much works perfectly and I can now see where I was going wrong. You have been very helpful my friend. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @TrueY really sorry about this I was sure this was working earlier. It's creating the files with no data in them, it works from command line but not script..... One last question do you know how I would insert another blank line below the header, it's for a mail merge and we want the first label blank on every run. I've been hunting for a solution all day.....

Comment: Kent's ideas?  He copy and pasted from my answer!  Didn't even change the name of the array!  (The tone of this comment is not intended to be anything other than an expression of appreciation to Kent for the flattery.)

Comment: @Paul: Empty line: `print hdr"\n">$3".csv"`. Could You insert the `test.awk` and the line You are calling the script into your question? (And pls remove wrong script from the end!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: IMHO his solution is working, Your not. See header and indexing. So it is at least an improvement.

Comment: @TrueY thanks & updated question. I'm not sure what all these other comments are about but thanks for your help once again.

Comment: @Paul: For Empty line after header try: `print hdr"\n">$3".csv"`; for empty files you could try `print $0>$3".csv"`. Pls provide feedback!

Comment: @Paul: I found the problem in your script! `{print>"$3.csv"}` is wrong! `{print>$3".csv"}` is the correct version!

Comment: @TrueY Blank line works a treat thanks again :) Did you see my comments on sorting data? & maybe using data from another file? not sure if I'm pushing my luck with AWK or not, it seems really powerful...

Comment: @Paul: I modified my answer to include the blank line. For sorting you can use the `sort` command. Try `sort /?` in `cmd`.

Comment: @TrueY mate you really do give this place a good name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{out=$3".csv";
    if!(out in a)print h> out; print $0 > out;a[out]}' test.csv
```

Comment: C:\tmp>awk -f test.awk
awk: test.awk:1: awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{out=$3".csv";
awk: test.awk:1:         ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {
    getline header
} 
{
    out=$3".csv"
    if (!($3 in seen)) { 
        print header > out 
    }
    print $0 > out
    seen[$3]
}' test.csv
```

#### Windows version: (Not tested)

```
awk " FS =\",\"
BEGIN {
    getline header
} 
{
    out=$3\".csv\"
    if (!($3 in seen)) { 
        print header > out 
    }
    print $0 > out
    seen[$3]
}" test.csv
```

Comment: C:\tmp>awk -f test.awk
awk: test.awk:1: awk -F, '
awk: test.awk:1:         ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: @Paul You are running it in windows machine. Use `"` instead of `'` like you have in your script.

Comment: Sorry I thought if I saved it as a .awk then this wouldn;t matter so I tried that. changed for " and then got this:

Comment: awk -F, "
BEGIN {
    getline header
} 
{
    out=$1\".csv\"
    if (!(out in seen)) { 
        print header > out 
    }
    print $0 > out
    seen[out]
}" test.csv

C:\tmp>awk -f test.awk
awk: test.awk:1: awk -F, "
awk: test.awk:1:         ^ unterminated string

Comment: @Paul added the windows version. Not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ output=$3".csv"; if( !($0 in a)) print "header" > output; a[$0]
    print > output}' FS=, test.csv
```

Comment: C:\tmp>awk -f test.awk
awk: test.awk:1: awk '{ output=$3".csv"; if( !($0 in a)) print "header" > output
; a[$0] print > output}' FS=, test.csv
awk: test.awk:1:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: @paul Do not invoke this in an awk script.  This is to be invoked from sh.

Comment: IMHO this is incorrect. The files should be separated by `$3` (or by `output`) not `$0`. Also should be extracted from the input file.