# AWK Split large CSV file with headers and print output files based on column value

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file of around 800 mb which I need to split up using AWK.
The file has a column with ID's in them which I want to use to split the file on.
I'm familiar/know how to accomplish this with Perl but not with AWK since I've only used it a few times.
(In perl I would use the Text::CSV module but I don't have the option in this case)

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16795137 which is basically what I want but with a small alteration. It has to contain an if statement so it will only print if the column I want to split it on is a digit. This is necessary because the file column can shift sometimes and I want to send the non-digit lines to a seperate file (junk.csv).

I'm using the windows cmd version for testing right now but I'll eventually run it on linux. (Below original code)

```
awk -F, "NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr\"\n\">$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}" test.csv
```

And my intention is this:

```
awk -F";" "{if ($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/){"NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3\".csv\"}{print>$3\".csv\"}"" test.csv
```

I can't figure out how to do this in AWK (just yet). The double quotes are also throwing me off (because of the windows version). Where am I going wrong?

This is my error output:

```
awk: {if($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3.csv};else print>junk.csv}
awk:                           ^ syntax error
awk: {if($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3.csv};else print>junk.csv}
awk:                                                      ^ syntax error
awk: {if($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3.csv};else print>junk.csv}
awk:                                                                                                     ^ syntax error
awk: {if($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) NR==1{hdr=$0;next}!($3 in files){files[$3]=1;print hdr>$3".csv"}{print>$3.csv};else print>junk.csv}
awk:                                                                                                                    ^ syntax error
errcount: 4
```

This is my (sample) data:

```
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10004766;12.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29007085.jpg;5.95;95074666117
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233
10009363;119.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29004907.jpg;5.95;9823036360
10009631;19.95;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29013097.jpg;5.95;20689058198
10010119;9.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016592.jpg;5.95;80076014280
10012615;20.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/28772382.jpg;5.95;3948187983
10015250;14.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29015812.jpg;5.95;93962045440
10019190;69.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29010968.jpg;5.95;948187983
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10034957;34.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29000529.jpg;5.95;42872898825
10041967;24.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28781700.jpg;5.95;91229911080
10045277;59.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29010583.jpg;5.95;67365082290
10045795;10.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29002819.jpg;5.95;19422308188
10048375;26.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002270.jpg;5.95;95082912275
10052550;19.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016347.jpg;5.95;7368425436
```

And I want to accomplish this:

```
File --> 26.csv
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10048375;26.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002270.jpg;5.95;95082912275

File --> 48.csv
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10004766;12.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29007085.jpg;5.95;95074666117
10009631;19.95;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29013097.jpg;5.95;20689058198
10010119;9.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016592.jpg;5.95;80076014280
10015250;14.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29015812.jpg;5.95;93962045440
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10045795;10.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29002819.jpg;5.95;19422308188
10052550;19.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016347.jpg;5.95;7368425436

File --> 53.csv
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10009363;119.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29004907.jpg;5.95;9823036360
10012615;20.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/28772382.jpg;5.95;3948187983
10019190;69.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29010968.jpg;5.95;948187983
10034957;34.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29000529.jpg;5.95;42872898825

File --> 65.csv
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
10041967;24.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28781700.jpg;5.95;91229911080
10045277;59.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29010583.jpg;5.95;67365082290
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the `awk` as

```
awk -F\; '{print > $3".csv"}' input
```

Will produce the following `csv` files with content

```
26.csv
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10048375;26.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002270.jpg;5.95;95082912275
48.csv
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10004766;12.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29007085.jpg;5.95;95074666117
10009631;19.95;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29013097.jpg;5.95;20689058198
10010119;9.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016592.jpg;5.95;80076014280
10015250;14.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29015812.jpg;5.95;93962045440
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10045795;10.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29002819.jpg;5.95;19422308188
10052550;19.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29016347.jpg;5.95;7368425436
53.csv
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10009363;119.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29004907.jpg;5.95;9823036360
10012615;20.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/28772382.jpg;5.95;3948187983
10019190;69.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29010968.jpg;5.95;948187983
10034957;34.99;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29000529.jpg;5.95;42872898825
65.csv
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
10041967;24.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28781700.jpg;5.95;91229911080
10045277;59.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29010583.jpg;5.95;67365082290
```

**NOTE**

If you want to send the lines which have non digits in column 3 to `junk.csv` a small change in the above awk can be helpfull

```
awk -F\; '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print > $3".csv"; next} {print > "junk.csv"}' input
```

- `$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/` performs a regex match on column 3 and if it matches, sends to corresponding csv file. else the line is written to `junk.csv`

**OR**

a much simpler version like

```
awk -F\; '{file=$3~/^[0-9]+$/?$3:"junk";print >file".csv"}'
```

Thanks to  Jidder for the suggestion.

Comment: Note `print` suffices, `print $0` is not necessary. Also, to check that a field is numeric / is not, you can use `/^[0-9]+$/`. This will match all having only digits (and at least one).

Comment: @fedorqui I have made the change with `print`. Thank you for that. But am not sure about your second point sorry. I have written it as `$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/` which matches only digits

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. When I commented it you had something a bit different, like `$3 ~ /[0-9]+/` which would match rows like `23a`.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah first i wrote something like that. Changed that when i realized it was wrong. Anyways thank you  for pointing that :)

Comment: Could also do the junk one this way `awk -F\; '{file=$3~/^[0-9]+$/?$3:"junk";print >file".csv"}'`

Comment: @Jidder more cryptic and simple. I liked it. will add to my answer :) Thank you

Comment: Wow already good feedback, thx! But i'm wondering.. does this work on a large file. I remember something about closing it when it has to output many files. (In my case 300 seperate csv files).

Comment: @Jan It should work. Try out and let us know if you run into truobles

Comment: @Jan If your worried about closing files `awk -F\; '{file=$3~/^[0-9]+$/?$3:"junk";print >file".csv";close(file".csv")}'`

Comment: You're right nu11p01n73R, works wonderfully! only one thing, it writes the "junk" to ".csv" and not "junk.csv" just curious as to why not. Anything to do that i'm running it on windows now? Jidder, thanks for showing me how to close files. Is it possible to keep the header and place it in each output file? I'm trying to incorporate it now but no luck.

Comment: Got the junk filename working, had to do with the double quotes that need to be escaped on the windows version. Now for the linux testing..

Comment: @Jan It can be because of that am getting the junk values in `junk.csv` on a linux system