# Split up files according to column value perl text::csv

Tags: perl, csv

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973983/awk-split-large-csv-file-with-headers-and-print-output-files-based-on-column-val) before how to do this with AWK but it doesn't handle it all that well.
The data has semicolons in quoted fields, which AWK doesn't take into account. So I was trying it in perl with the text::csv module so I don't have to think about that. The problem is I don't know how to output it to files based on a column value.

Short example from previous question, the data:

```
10002394;"""22.98""";48;New York;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10025155;27.99;65;Chicago;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10003062;19.99;26;San Francisco;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10003122;13.0;53;"""Miami""";http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10029650;27.99;48;New York;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10007645;20.99;65;Chicago;"""http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg""";5.95;10201848233    
10025825;12.99;65;Chicago;"""http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg""";5.95;93962025367
```

The desired result:

```
File --> 26.csv
10003062;19.99;26;San Francisco;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049

File --> 48.csv
10002394;22.98;48;New York;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10029650;27.99;48;New York;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452

File --> 53.csv
10003122;13.0;53;Miami;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059

File --> 65.csv
10025155;27.99;65;Chicago;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10007645;20.99;65;Chicago;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233    
10025825;12.99;65;Chicago;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
```

This is what I have so far. **EDIT: Modified code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
#use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my $inputfile  = shift || die "Give input and output names!\n";

open my $infile, '<', $inputfile or die "Sourcefile in use / not found :$!\n";

#binmode($infile, ":encoding(utf8)");

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1,sep_char => ";",quote_space => 0,eol => $/});

my %fh;
my %count;
my $country;
my $date = localtime->strftime('%y%m%d');

open(my $fh_report, '>', "report$date.csv");

$csv->getline($infile);

while ( my $elements = $csv->getline($infile)){

EDITED IN:
__________ 
next unless ($elements->[29] =~ m/testdata/);

for (@$elements){
        next if ($elements =~ /apple|orange|strawberry/);
        }
__________

for (@$elements){
        s/\"+/\"/g;
        }

    my $filename = $elements->[2];
    $shop = $elements->[3] .";". $elements->[2];

    $count{$country}++;

        $fh{$filename} ||= do {
            open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename . ".csv") or die "Could not open file '$filename'";
            $fh;
        };

    $csv->print($fh{$filename}, $elements); 
    }

    #print $fh_report Dumper(\%count);
    foreach my $name (reverse sort { $count{$a} <=> $count{$b} or $a cmp $b } keys %count) {
        print $fh_report "$name;$count{$name}\n";
    }

close $fh_report;
```

Errors:

```
Can't call method "print" on an undefined value at sort_csv_delimiter.pl line 28, <$infile> line 2
```

I've been messing around with this but I'm totally at a loss. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want hash of cached file handles,

```
my %fh;
while ( my $elements = $csv->getline( $infile ) ) {

  my $filename = $elements->[2];

  $fh{$filename} ||= do {
    open my $fh, ">", "$filename.csv" or die $!;
    $fh;
  };

  # $csv->combine(@$elements);
  $csv->print($fh{$filename}, $elements);     
}
```

Comment: It should probably be `$filename . ".csv"`. I am also thinking open mode should be `>`, since otherwise running the script more than once will append additional data. Also, since `$elements` never changes, there is no need to try and reassemble the array. `combine` is also used with `string()`, so it is redundant here.

Comment: @TLP I've modified my code and combined both your feedback (thanks to both of course) but now it gives me 2 errors. It all looks proper now so I don't understand why its giving me the errors (see first post). Can you see what I missed?

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks, modified it slightly (see first post). Oh and the file is not sorted so shouldn't the open mode be in append mode? I don't want to sort it because the actual file is 1.5GB and will probably take more time?

Comment: @Сухой27 Modified it but getting new error (see original post). And a little confused atm. How come it's undefined?

Comment: @Сухой27 Then it says: Useless use of private variable in void context at sort_csv_delimiter.pl line 25. Which got me confused again

Comment: @Jan take also note that `$fh{$filename} || do` is meaningless. You're not careful.

Comment: @Jan `||` is very different from `||=`.

Comment: @Сухой27 Oh wauw, sorry..had no idea! I'm still learning.. What is the difference? as TLP pointed out..they are. It's working btw, got  wide character warning though. Fixed it with open encoding(utf8) mode.

Comment: @Jan check `perldoc perlop`. In short `x ||= y` is same as `x = x || y`

Comment: @Сухой27 Hi, I have a follow-up question. I'm using the code and use a next if/unless when a element contains a certain word to remove the line but how do I match against the whole line and not just a element? In my edited code you can see a edited section what I tried but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an instance of your stated problem -- occurrences of the semicolon separator character `;` within quoted fields -- but you are correct that [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) will handle it correctly.

This short program reads your example data from the `DATA` file handle and prints the result to `STDOUT`. I presume you know how to read from or write to different files if you wish.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ';', eol => $/ });

my @data;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA) ) {
  push @data, $row;
}

my $file;

for my $row ( sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] or $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @data ) {
  unless (defined $file and $file == $row->[2]) {
    $file = $row->[2];
    printf "\nFile --> %d.csv\n", $file;
  }
  $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
}

__DATA__
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233    
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
```

**output**

```
File --> 26.csv
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049

File --> 48.csv
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452

File --> 53.csv
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059

File --> 65.csv
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;"10201848233    "
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
```

---

**Update**

I have just realised that your *"desired result"* isn't the output that you expect to see, but rather the way separate records are written to different files. This program solves that.

It looks from your question as though you want the data sorted in order of the first field as well, and so I have read all of the file into memory and printed a sorted version to the relevant files. I have also used [`autodie`](https://metacpan.org/module/autodie) to avoid having to code status checks for all the IO operations.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ';', eol => $/ });

my @data;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA) ) {
  push @data, $row;
}

my ($file, $fh);

for my $row ( sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] or $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @data ) {
  unless (defined $file and $file == $row->[2]) {
    $file = $row->[2];
    open $fh, '>', "$file.csv";
  }
  $csv->print($fh, $row);
}

close $fh;

__DATA__
10002394;22.98;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29012827.jpg;5.95;93962094820
10025155;27.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29011075.jpg;5.95;14201021349
10003062;19.99;26;http://testdata.com/bla/29002816.jpg;5.95;17012725049
10003122;13.0;53;http://testdata.com/bla/29019899.jpg;5.95;24404000059
10029650;27.99;48;http://testdata.com/bla/29003007.jpg;5.95;3692164452
10007645;20.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/28798580.jpg;5.95;10201848233    
10025825;12.99;65;http://testdata.com/bla/29017837.jpg;5.95;93962025367
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I have done this using Awk (gawk):

```
awk --assign col=2 'BEGIN { if(!(col ~/^[1-9]/)) exit 2; outname = "part-%s.txt"; } !/^#/ { out = sprintf(outname, $col); print > out; }' bigfile.txt

other_process data | awk --assign col=2 'BEGIN { if(!(col ~/^[1-9]/)) exit 2; outname = "part-%s.txt"; } !/^#/ { out = sprintf(outname, $col); print > out; }'
```

Let me explain the awk script:

```
BEGIN {                          # execution block before reading any file (once)
  if(!(col ~/^[1-9]/)) exit 2;   # assert the `col` variable is a positive number
  outname = "part-%s.txt";       # formatting string of the output file names
}
!/^#/ {                          # only process lines not starting with '#' (header/comments in various data files)
  out = sprintf(outname, $col);  # format the output file name, given the value in column `col`
  print > out;                   # put the line to that file
}
```

If you like you can add a variable to specify a custom filename or use the current filename (or STDIN) as prefix:

```
NR == 1 {                                                         # at the first file (not BEGIN, as we might need FILENAME)
  if(!(col ~/^[1-9]/)) exit 2;                                    # assert the `col` variable is a positive number
  if(!outname) outname = (FILENAME == "-" ? "STDIN" : FILENAME);  # if `outname` variable was not provided (with `-v/--assign`), use current filename or STDIN
  if(!(outname ~ /%s/)) outname = outname ".%s";                  # if `outname` is not a formatting string - containing %s - append it
}
!/^#/ {                                                           # only process lines not starting with '#' (header/comments in various data files)
  out = sprintf(outname, $col);                                   # format the output file name, given the value in column `col`
  print > out;                                                    # put the line to that file
}
```

Note: if you provide multiple input files, only the first file's name will be used as output prefix. To support multiple input files and multiple prefixes, you can use `FNR == 1` instead and add another variable to distinguish between user-provided `outname` and the auto-generated one.